# Implementing a custom FormsAuthenticationProvider using Owin, Katana, and Nancy

Tags: nancy, owin, katana

I am working on implementing a custom `FormsAuthenticationProvider` and I'm getting a middleware conversion error.

```
No conversion available between System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2
[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and Microsoft.Owin.OwinMiddleware
Parameter name: signature
```

My stack includes

- Owin
- Katana
- Nancy

*My specific question would be any advice on where to look for an example on how to implement a custom `FormsAuthenticationProvider`? Unless someone can spot my problem.*

My implementation looks like:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseFormsAuthentication(new FormsAuthenticationOptions
            {
                LoginPath = "/login",
                LogoutPath = "/logout",
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                AuthenticationType = Constants.ChainLinkAuthType,
                CookieName = "chainlink.id",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                Provider = kernel.Get<IFormsAuthenticationProvider>()
            });
```

If I remove the `app.UseFormsAuthentication(...)` the application runs without error.

**Full Stack Trace**

```
[ArgumentException: No conversion available between System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and Microsoft.Owin.OwinMiddleware
Parameter name: signature]
   Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.Convert(Type signature, Object app) +328
   Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.BuildInternal(Type signature) +336
   Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.Build(Type returnType) +42
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +650
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +86
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build() +185
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +416
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinApplication.get_Instance() +35
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): No conversion available between     System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and Microsoft.Owin.OwinMiddleware
Parameter name: signature]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr,  HttpContext context) +254
```

**Executable Source Code** (Just F5 it and you'll get the error immediately)

https://github.com/cnwilkin/ChainLink/tree/spike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try updating the version of Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package to the latest RC as well and try? You have all other Owin* dlls in rc but this is 1.0.0. Could be causing the issue. Also please use Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies instead of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Forms. The Forms package has been renamed to Cookies now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed everything.

Comment: I went into nuget and clicked update all and the conversion error went away